# EclipseLink non-entity exception

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I get the following exception using EclipseLink:
The Enterprise entity maintains a @OneToMany relationship with the Client entity. Both entities are included in the persistance.xml file.

I use inner builder classes inside both the Enterprise and Client entities, not sure if this can be the issue.

**Exception Message**

```
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
    Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [geography] failed.
    Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
    Exception Description: [class za.co.lot24media.ws.entity.Client] uses a non-entity [class za.co.lot24media.ws.entity.Enterprise] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field enterprise].
```

**Logging output with ALL option**

**Enterprise**

```
[EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-24 08:43:26.842--ServerSession(1330106945)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class za.co.lot24media.ws.entity.Enterprise] is set to [FIELD].

[EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-24 08:43:27.005--ServerSession(1330106945)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The target entity (reference) class for the many to one mapping element [field enterprise] is being defaulted to: class za.co.lot24media.ws.entity.Enterprise.

[EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-24 08:43:27.447--ServerSession(1330106945)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class za.co.lot24media.ws.entity.Enterprise] is being defaulted to: Enterprise.
```

**Client**

```
    [EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-24 08:43:26.932--ServerSession(1330106945)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The target entity (reference) class for the one to many mapping element [field clients] is being defaulted to: class za.co.lot24media.ws.entity.Client.

[EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-24 08:43:27.011--ServerSession(1330106945)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class za.co.lot24media.ws.entity.Client] is set to [FIELD].

        [EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-24 08:43:27.6--ServerSession(1330106945)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class za.co.lot24media.ws.entity.Client] is being defaulted to: Client.
```

**Enterprise Class**

```
package za.co.lot24media.ws.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import za.co.lot24media.ws.common.DomainEntity;

/**
 *
 * @author Hendré Louw <hendre@lot24media.co.za>
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "enterprise", schema = "enterprise")
public class Enterprise extends DomainEntity<Enterprise> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "enterprise_id")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Company company;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "configuration_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Configuration configuration;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprise")
    private List<Client> clients;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprise")
    private List<Application> applications;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprise")
    private List<Operator> operators;

    public Enterprise() {
    }

    private Enterprise(Builder builder) {
        clients = new ArrayList<>();
        applications = new ArrayList<>();
        operators = new ArrayList<>();

        Company c1 = new Company.Builder(this, builder.country, builder.legalPerson, builder.companyName)
                .build();

        this.company = c1;
        this.configuration = builder.configuration;
        clients.stream().forEach((c) -> {
            c.setEnterprise(this);
        });
        this.clients.addAll(clients);
        applications.stream().forEach((a) -> {
            a.setEnterprise(this);
        });
        this.applications.addAll(applications);
        operators.stream().forEach((o) -> {
            o.setEnterprise(this);
        });
        this.operators.addAll(operators);
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private final String companyName;
        private final Country country;
        private final LegalPerson legalPerson;
        private Configuration configuration;
        private final List<Client> clients;
        private final List<Application> applications;
        private final List<Operator> operators;

        public Builder(Country country, LegalPerson legalPerson, String companyName) {
            assert companyName != null;
            assert country != null;
            this.country = country;
            this.companyName = companyName;
            this.legalPerson = legalPerson;
            clients = new ArrayList<>();
            applications = new ArrayList<>();
            operators = new ArrayList<>();
            configuration = new Configuration();
        }

        public Builder withClient(Client client) {
            assert client != null;
            clients.add(client);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withApplication(Application application) {
            assert application != null;
            applications.add(application);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withOperator(Operator operator) {
            assert operator != null;
            operators.add(operator);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
            assert configuration != null;
            this.configuration = configuration;
            return this;
        }

        public Enterprise build() {
            return new Enterprise(this);
        }

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    public void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }

    public void setClients(List<Client> clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }

    public List<Application> getApplications() {
        return applications;
    }

    public void setApplications(List<Application> applications) {
        this.applications = applications;
    }

    public List<Operator> getOperators() {
        return operators;
    }

    public void setOperators(List<Operator> operators) {
        this.operators = operators;
    }

}
```

**Client Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client", schema = "enterprise")
public class Client extends DomainEntity<Client> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "client_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "enterprise_id", nullable = false)
    private Enterprise enterprise;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    public Client() {
    }
```

**Client Static Builder Class**

```
    public static class Builder {

    private final Enterprise enterprise;
    private final Company company;

    public Builder(Enterprise enterprise, Company company) {
        assert enterprise != null;
        assert company != null;
        this.enterprise = enterprise;
        this.company = company;
    }

    public Builder(Enterprise enterprise, Country country, LegalPerson legalPerson, String companyName) {
        assert enterprise != null;
        assert country != null;
        assert legalPerson != null;
        assert companyName != null;
        this.enterprise = enterprise;
        this.company = new Company.Builder(enterprise, country, legalPerson, companyName)
                .build();
    }

    public Client build() {
        Client c = new Client(this);

        // Link enterprise
        c.getEnterprise().getClients().add(c);            
        return c;
    }

}
```

Comment: and you specified Enterprise in persistence.xml?

Comment: Show us the whole code of Enterprise, starting at the package statement, and including the imports.

Comment: Turn on EclipseLink logging to finest and check for other issues and warning while it is deploying the persistence unit.  For instance, has it tried processing the Enterprise entity, and is it able to load the DomainEntity root for both entities?

Comment: It seems the issue is with the static builder class. When I remove the builder class the issue is resolved. When I add the builder, the issue returns. Any suggestions?